# It is possible to check in django rest query filter using .upper()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to compare value in db with request.data after changing both to **upper case**. Is it possible like this?

```
str_code = CustomerAccount.objects.filter(strAccountCode.upper() = 
request.data['strAccountCode'].upper(),chrDocumentStatus='N')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the case-insensitive exact match, [`iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) filter:

```
str_code = CustomerAccount.objects.filter(
    strAccountCode__iexact=request.data['strAccountCode'],
    chrDocumentStatus='N'
)
```

which translated to SQL is going to be something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE strAccountCode ILIKE '[value]';
```